# Funcion de factorización recursiva Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, recursión

Me encuentro tratando de realizar una función recursiva en la que obtengamos los mínimos denominadores en un array de un numero pasado por parámetro, por ejemplo factoreo(8) debería devolver [2,2,2] ya que 2x2x2 es 8, el problema que tengo es que no se me ocurre bien como encarar la función, por el momento tengo hecho esto

```
 function factores(num) {
  if(num % 2 != 0){
      return num
  } else {
    
  };
};
```

Comment: ¿Tenes claro como se obtienen los _mínimos denominadores_? Es decir, cual es el proceso que hay realizar para ir obteniéndolos. Por ejemplo, para el número `12` ¿cual es el paso a paso para obtenerlos?

Answer (score 0):

Si no entiendo mal, los comunes denominadores pueden ser varios por lo tanto se deberia colectar una lista de arrays con los minimos denominadores posibles

```
function factores(num, denominadores, collect) {
  const resultado = denominadores.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);

  if(resultado === num) {
    collect.push(denominadores)
  } else if(resultado < num) {
    for(let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      factores(num, [...denominadores, i], collect);
    }
  }
};

const denominadoresColectados = [];
factores(12, [], denominadoresColectados);

console.log(denominadoresColectados);
```

Este ejemplo retornaria esta matriz

```
[
  [ 2, 2, 3 ],
  [ 2, 3, 2 ],
  [ 2, 6 ],
  [ 3, 2, 2 ],
  [ 3, 4 ],
  [ 4, 3 ],
  [ 6, 2 ]
]
```

Aquí el numero 1 debe ser descartado ya que de lo contraria generaría infinitos denominadores con 1, por eso el bucle comienza desde 2

Espero te sirva